# Comparison of a meta analysis pooled estimate to an estimate from primary research

Tags: hypothesis-testing, meta-analysis, biostatistics, pooling

I  want to compare the pooled estimate (mean change in two time points) of a meta analysis that has been published, to the same estimate from a primary research that i am carrying out (on my own dataset).  Is there a  statistical test for this comparison or do i just compare overlapping of confidence intervals? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought a Wald-type test would work here.

$$
z = \frac{M_1 - M_2}{\sqrt{se_1^2 + se_2^2}}
$$
 where $M_1$ is the mean from the meta-analysis, $M_2$ is your mean and $se$ are the corresponding standard errors. You then have a $z$ to test.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. This was actually my original thought, so it really good to know it makes sense not only to me. I just couldn't find any related references.